# Scroll chaining. Scrolling inner and then outer scroll as one gesture in web browser

Tags: css, web, overflow, gesture, overscroll

My goal is to implement behaviour as it is shown in following gif but with one gesture:

1. Touch "Birmingham"
2. Move finger up what should cause "Temperature in my city" being hidden
3. Still moving finger up inner scroll should start scrolling
4. Change direction down what should cause inner scroll direction change
5. When inner scroll gets the very top outer scroll starts scrolling making "Temperature in my city" visible
6. Release finger

Question:
Is it possible to achieve such behaviour with css scroll chaining. I try to use `overscroll-behavior` css property but it seems it gives far less options to what I need

For sure everything can be implement just with one scroll but I plan to make css transitions for "Temperature in my city" element where the transitions will be dependent on outer scroll position but independent on inner scroll.

Thx :-)

[Implementation in CodePen](https://codepen.io/duo-pendulum/pen/KKoRmKL)

[image: Scrolling inner and outer with several touches]